# Typescript enum forces invalid require() in common js

Tags: typescript, enums, commonjs

file.ts:

```
import { EnumThing } from "./dep";
```

dep.ts:

```
export enum EnumThing {
  ....
}
```

Now if I build both files, insid `file.cjs` I get:

```
var import_external_dep = ___toESM(require("@stuff/externaldep"));
var import_dep = require("./dep"); // <- invalid
```

which appears to be invalid js because I get module not found error in node.js. The external require seems to work fine tho.

I tried to manually wrap that require in ___toESM() but still I get the module not found error.

Any idea what to do? I really need that enum separated in another file.

Comment: Have you tried `export const enum EnumThing{ ... }`.  The only value in not having `const` is that the TypeScript compiler preserves the reverse mapping for debugging purposes,  but that is complex and may be causing your problem.